# List job applications as freelancer, what does the output field 'status: Current status of the job application' ints map to?

Tags: upwork-api

The Upwork API documentation shows that the '[List job applications as freelancer](https://developers.upwork.com/?lang=python#contracts-and-offers_list-job-applications-as-freelancer)' endpoint returns an 'output field' called 'status'.  I can confirm that the value returned is typically a string with a value of 2-9.  I am trying to understand what these values map to.

The only plausible solution I have found is the '[List Reasons](https://developers.upwork.com/?lang=python#metadata_list-tests)' endpoint, though the mapping does not really make sense in a few of the cases I looked at.

Does anyone know what the status codes returned by the List job applications as freelancer endpoint map to?

Thanks a million!

Answer (score 0):

The statuses should correspond to the following values:

- Created = 1 // deprecated
- Accepted = 2
- Declined = 3
- Withdrawn = 4
- Replaced = 5 // deprecated
- Offered  = 6
- Activated = 7
- Archived = 8
- Rejected = 9 // deprecated
- Hired = 10
- Pending = 11
- Invalid = 12